# Yii 1.1: how to set custom status code?

Tags: php, yii

Can I render a custom 404 page by using a `$this->render(...)` method combined with setting a 404 code?

Framework: Yii 1.1

Comment: For a vanilla PHP version, just do: `http_response_code(404);` and then you should be able to render your custom 404 view as normal in Yii.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Is there some more Yii-ish way to do so?

Comment: I actually don't know.

Answer (score 4):

Yii 1.1 does not have a response abstraction (it was introduced in Yii 2.0), so there is no yii-way of doing this - you should either use `http_response_code(404)` to set response code or send headers directly by using `header()`:

```
$httpVersion = Yii::app()->request->getHttpVersion();
header("HTTP/$httpVersion 404 Not Found");
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one =>

if ($error = Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) {

```
        switch ($error['code']) {
            case 404:
                $this->render('error404', array('error' => $error));
                break;
            case 500:
                $this->render('error500', array('error' => $error));
                break;
        }
    }
```